# Trying to install sql_server_2014_enterprise_edition_x64_dvd Windows 7(Ultimate) 64Bit OS

Tags: sql-server, installation, errors, sql-server-2014

Im receiving the following error after the Set-up checks Global rules
[image]

It shows the following error. any idea why this issue occurs :( ?by the way this machine was formatted yesterday and this is a fresh installation.!Your help is appreciated..

> ### TITLE: SQL Server Setup failure.
>
> SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:
>
> No room is available to display rows..
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&EvtType=0x52CFE887%25400xE9BC3D64
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

Extracted from the Log file

> Exception summary: The following is an exception stack listing the
>   exceptions in outermost to innermost order Inner exceptions are being
>   indented
>
> Exception type: System.InvalidOperationException
>       Message: 
>           No room is available to display rows.
>       HResult : 0x80131509
>       Data: 
>         HelpLink.EvtType = 0x52CFE887@0xE9BC3D64
>         DisableWatson = true
>       Stack: 
>           at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.set_FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex(Int32
>   value)
>           at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.InstallWizard.RunRuleProgressController.RulesEngineExecutionCompleted(Object
>   sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)

Comment: In view of your comment on the answer ([here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84153/trying-to-install-sql-server-2014-enterprise-edition-x64-dvd-windows-7ultimate/87053#comment151744_84156)), I've closed the question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I think you should be installing Developer Edition as Windows 7 is not a server-OS.  Make sure you have admin rights on your machine.  It may also be worth trying the different install media?

However it looks like there is an open [connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/925846/no-room-is-available-to-display-rows) for this error and further discussion [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fff2f0f2-9948-4c13-add7-041e634c0e6d/installing-sql-server-2014-entreprise-error?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade)

As a workaround, you could use some of your Azure credits to spin up one of the pre-prepared VMs which already have SQL Server 2014 installed, or try Express edition.

Comment: Its little strange but after running the installation for the 3rd time again this issue did not re-occur again have no idea what happened ,thanks for your answer anyway!